# Executing mysql commands in python script

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite

Is it possible to execute mysql commands such as the ones below within a python script?

mysql> show databases;

mysql> show tables;

For example, executing sql queries within a python script can be done by the following:

```
connection = MySQLdb.connect()
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from table;")
```

How would one write this to execute mysql commands?

The motivation is that using "show tables" is quicker than writing a sql statement to show all the table names within a database.

Comment: `show database` is not an SQLite command. What is your actual goal?

Comment: Thanks for the catch! Updated the question.

Comment: "show tables" is quicker because it outputs nothing but an error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sqlite3 as lite
import sys

con = None


con = lite.connect('dbname')

cur = con.cursor()    
cur.execute('select * from table')

rows = cur.fetchall()

for row in rows:
   print row
```

Comment: Try blocks require a following except block. Is there any specific exception you're aiming to catch?

Answer (score 0):

The SQLite library is designed as an embedded database, so it does not implement commands that would not be useful for applications.

There is the command `.tables`, but it is implemented by the [`sqlite3` command-line shell](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html), not by SQLite itself, so it is not available through Python. You have to use built-in mechnisms like [PRAGMA database_list](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_database_list) or `SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table';`.